# Firebase click_action not working

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've got a problem with FCM, as documented by the Firebase Team:

> click_action: Indicates the action associated with a user click on the notification. When this is set, an activity with a matching intent filter is launched when user clicks the notification.

I know its been discussed, but according to my understanding this should be possible from the firebase console by what I understand from the documentation. It doesn't say its for data-messages it clearly says its a field for notification-messages, and as I understand, these are the ones that the Firebase Console send.

Can anyone clarify this.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[click_action](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) is not available thorough the Firebase console at this time.

You are correct in saying that the console send notification messages however it does not allow you to set the click_action field of the notification message. To use click_action you have to send a notification message using the REST API where all the notification message fields are available.

Note that the custom data that is added via the console becomes key/value pairs in the data payload that will accompany the notification message. Example structure:

```
{
  "to": <topic>,
  "notification": {
    <notification payload>
  },
  "data": {
    <data payload, console custom data key/value pairs go here>
  }
}
```

So the click_action is part of the notification payload but you must use the REST API to use it at this point. I understand that this is not clear, I will look into possible doc updates to make this clearer.

Answer (score 3):

The console seems to not support click_action so far. You either have to use the API to trigger the notification or try to pass the click_action parameter via the custom data fields in the advanced section when composing a notification in Firebase Console (I have not tried this so far, but might work).

Comment: I've tried sending that parameter through custom data but won't be taken into account with the intent-filters from the manifest...all I could do was get the intent in the launcher activity and redirect using this parameter to the corresponding activity...but its a poor solution

Comment: But it's the best you'll get from the console. The console is far from perfect and has many missing features right now

Answer (score 1):

You can use following snippet of Rest Service to send push Message from RestClient (Postman)

```
Method : POST 
URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Header:
Authorization : key=<FCM SERVER LEGACY KEY>
Content-Type: application/json

Body: 

{

        "notification": {
            "title": "Firebase notification",
            "message": "I am firebase notification. you can customise me. enjoy",
            "click_action": "OPEN_ACTIVITY",
            "sound":"default",

        }
    ,
    "to": "<Your device FCM Token - Getting it from the FirebaseInstanceIdService>"
}
```

At your Manifest file - Include the Intent filter to match the Click_action value:
Ex:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.NotificationActivity"
            >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```